# windows command line pass through quotes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a command that I want to pass into a batch file that contains quotes.  What i want to do is pass in the following parameter as a single parameter into the bat file:

```
set parameter=-c myfirstparameter -p "also my first parameter"

C:\mybat.bat parameter
```

Unfortunatly this ends up being:

```
%1 = -c
%2 = myfirstparameter
etc
```

What I want is

```
%1 = -c myfirstparameter -p "also my first parameter"
```

Comment: Do you actually want quotes around "also my first parameter"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a Batch File an Argument Containing a Quote Containing a Space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618690/passing-a-batch-file-an-argument-containing-a-quote-containing-a-space)

Comment: Check out the question above.  I especially like the workaround of outputting it to a temporary file if that's an option.

Comment: @DevilsAdvocate That temp file solution does work, however I would wish not to do that if I didn't have to

Comment: Okay, I've spent entirely too much time on this.  It's interesting, but I have to give up.  The closest I got was `-c myfirstparameter -p ""also my first parameter"` but I'm not sure why it still has the 2 double-quotes.

Comment: I am not understanding why you would pass arguments to a batch file just to then use them as arguments to another program?

Comment: Matt, with a minor modification, @dbenham's answer does what you want without the temporary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of using a temp file ([as found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618690/passing-a-batch-file-an-argument-containing-a-quote-containing-a-space)) to pass the parameter:

**FIRST.BAT**

```
echo -c myfirstparameter -p "also my first parameter">dummy.txt
second.bat
```

**SECOND.BAT**

```
set /p param=<dummy.txt
echo %param%
```

Here is the raw output:

```
C:\temp\batchtest>first

echo -c myfirstparameter -p "also my first parameter" 1>dummy.txt

second.bat

set /p param= 0<dummy.txt

echo -c myfirstparameter -p "also my first parameter"
-c myfirstparameter -p "also my first parameter"

C:\temp\batchtest>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do what you want. Batch uses [space], [comma], [semicolon], [equal], [tab], and [0xFF] as token delimiters when parsing arguments. If you want a token delimiter literal within an argument value, then the delimiter must be quoted. It is impossible to escape a token delimiter. Therefore it is impossible to have a single parameter that has both quoted and unquoted token delimiter literals.

Presumably the top code in your question is wrong. In order to get the results you describe, you must have

```
set parameter=-c myfirstparameter -p "also my first parameter"
C:\mybat.bat %parameter%
```

The best way to handle such a situation is to pass your parameter by reference, which requires a modification to your mybat.bat.

Instead of retrieving the value via `%1`, you must enable delayed expansion and use `!%1!`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "argument1=!%1!"
```

With such an arrangement, you would indeed use the following to call the script:

```
set parameter=-c myfirstparameter -p "also my first parameter"
C:\mybat.bat parameter
```

Comment: `argument = !%1!` should be something like `set argument1=!%1!`

Comment: Also I like that you start out with "You cannot do what you want" then proceed to show him exactly how to do it :D

Comment: @DevilsAdvocate - Good point in your first comment. I modified my answer accordingly.